# Cómo hacer que el formulario de contacto html envie email a una dirección especifica?

Tags: html5, bootstrap, email

Soy completamente nuevo en esto del diseño web, y necesito una mano
He aqui el código del formulario en html, gracias de antemano

```
<div class="container">
    <section>
        <div class="page-header" id="contact">
            <h2><small></small></h2>
        </div> <!--End page header-->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <p></p>
                <address>

                </address>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <form action="" class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="user-name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Nombre</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user-name" placeholder="Ingrese su nombre"> 
                        </div>
                    </div> <!--End form-group-->

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="user-email" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user-email" placeholder="Ingrese su email"> 
                        </div>
                    </div> <!--End form-group-->

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="user-message" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Mensaje</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <textarea name="user-message" id="user-message" class="form-control" cols="20" rows="10" placeholder="Ingrese su mensaje"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div> <!--End form-group-->

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Enviar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Con HTML no haces nada más que dar la vista al usuario, para poder enviar un EMAIL necesitas de algún lenguaje de programación para hacer ese proceso.